# Dictionary application doesn't show all the dictionaries I can use

Tags: snow-leopard, dictionary

I have a problem with the Dictionary application: all in a sudden, without any changes on the preferences, the application doesn't show all the dictionaries I can look a word in the toolbar that appears under the title bar.
The Mac synchronizes its preferences with another Mac (through Mobile Me), but in the other Mac the application shows the usual list of dictionaries, as it is used to do, and how it should do basing on the application preferences.

What can I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: What happens if you reenable those dictionaries in the preferences?

Comment: They don't appear as tabs in the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by copying the setting file (com.apple.Dictionary.plist) from the other Mac.
I made a copy of the file, in the case I could have the same issue.